# Inequality question involving maximum value and three variables

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x, y, z > 0$ and $x + y + z = 1$, prove that

(a) $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq \frac{1}{3}$

(b) $x^2yz \leq \frac{1}{64}$

For the first part, since

$\begin{align} x+y+z=1 &\geq 3\cdot \sqrt[3]{xyz} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{9} &\geq \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2} \end{align}$

and thus

$\begin{align} x^2+y^2+z^2 &\geq 3 \cdot \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2} \\
\therefore x^2+y^2+z^2 &\geq \frac{1}{3} \blacksquare.  \end{align}$

I dont understand how i should proceed for the second part tho. Here is my attempt at it with weighted AM GM.

$\begin{align} 2x+y+z &\geq 4 \cdot \sqrt[4]{x^2yz} \\
\frac{1+x}{4} &\geq \sqrt[4]{x^2yz} \\
 \frac{x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1}{256} &\geq x^2yz \\ \end{align}$

But i don't get how i should proceed from here. Please check the solutions and help with the second part. Thanks

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h342283p1830987 on AoPS.

Comment: If you think a little bit more you wold have got this

Comment: Yes @SohamChatterjee probably. But I'v got so much to learn before the IMO that m kinda stressed out these days. I love maths and wish to participate of my own free will however the vastness definitely makes me nervous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b) apply AM/GM to $x$, $x$, $2y$ and $2z$. We get
$$\frac{2(x+y+z)}{4}\ge\sqrt[4]{4x^2yz}$$
etc.

Comment: I can't believe i didn't observe that! I gotta lot to learn man. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{2\times\frac{x}{2}+y+z}{4}\geq \sqrt[4]{\frac{x^2}{4}yz}=\frac{\sqrt[4]{x^2yz}}{\sqrt{2}}\implies x^2yz\leq \frac{4}{4^4}=\frac{1}{64}$$